# How to speed up the display of elements from the request?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm kinda new in React JS. My problem is when I load the page the elements from the backend appear for a very long time.This is my code of request:

```
const [cards, setCards] = useState<ICard[]>([])

interface CardsData {
    card: ICard[];
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchCards();
}, [])

async function fetchCards() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get<ICard[]>(
            `http://localhost:8080/backend/products.php`,
            {
                responseType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }
        );
        const cardsData = response.data;
        setCards(cardsData || []);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

I'd like to see the instant work of request when I'm loading the page. Or at least I could see some kind of preloading background of cards. Overall, what I'm trying to find here is to optimize the speed of loading.

Comment: You're never going to be able to 100% control the speed of things like Axios calls.  I find it best to create a loader (like a spinning circle -- Call it `<Loader />` and display it based on a state.  `const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)` Then make sure the loader shows when true -- `{( isLoading ) ? <Loader /> : <> Your Stuff You show Once you set Loading False </>}` --  You would set loading false in your Axios call when finished.  `setLoadting(false)`

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the use of [React-loading-Skeleton](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton) or other such libraries for your preloading effect.

How to make your fetching faster depends on your backend server and its implementation. Quite little can be done and said based on what you have provided.

Comment: This is a comment, not a definitive answer.

Comment: There is no definitive answer for a question that doesn't provide sufficient information.

Comment: Exactly, so you have options here.  You can comment, flag, upvote, downvote and vote the question closed (when you have the appropriate reputation).  These are all appropriate responses to unanswerable questions.  Maybe offer some advise on how OP can improve the question, or simply vote it closed.

Comment: What part of the code you'd like to see for a more complex answer?

Comment: It really depends on what is inside your `products.php`, and how it accepts and processes your GET request.

Comment: <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5173");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).